# UITableView differentiate between swiping from left-to-right & right-to-left

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How to differentiate between swiping from left-to-right & right-to-left in a UITableView cell.

Anyone has some ideas?

Comment: wait.. do you want to know how to use/enable the default edit behavior when you swipe from left to right or do you want handle that event in your own custom way?

Comment: nope, I want to handle the event that user swipe from right to left in a table view cell.

Comment: Swiping in either direction works. Or do you want to differentiate the two gestures?

Comment: oops, thanks Kenny, you are right, I want to differentiate between two gestures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting an OS > 3.2, you can use your own gesture recognizers. Otherwise, you can override touches moved in your UITableView or cell and evaluate the delta to determine swipe direction.